# How should I apply the vue-fb-customer-chat plugin in my nuxt 3 project?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, facebook-messenger, nuxt3, vite-plugin-development

I already install the [vue-fb-customer-chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fb-customer-chat) in my nuxt 3 project, and do copy pasting the code from "plugins/vue-fb-customer-chat.js",

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFbCustomerChat from 'vue-fb-customer-chat'

Vue.use(VueFbCustomerChat, {
  page_id: null, //  change 'null' to your Facebook Page ID,
  theme_color: '#333333', // theme color in HEX
  locale: 'en_US', // default 'en_US'
})
```

but there is an error saying `500 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')`

i tried to look to another question here in stack overflow, but says that and i also see that the official documentation is down, so im feeling that it is not working?